# Как выполнять функцию сначала после ее выполнения?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать выполнение функции после ее полного окончания(должна закончиться анимация) ? Нужно выполнять в течение 30 секунд, после этого завершаем выполнение.
P/S Пробовал сделать через while, но тогда происходит зацикливание и функция выполняется каждую секунду.

Функция:

```
function createFruit() {
        for(let i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
          //createFruit
          const randomFruit = Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length);
          const newFruit = document.createElement('div');
          const imageFruit = document.createElement('img');
          newFruit.id = fruit[randomFruit].id;
          newFruit.className = 'fruit';
          imageFruit.src = fruit[randomFruit].src;
          container.appendChild(newFruit);
          newFruit.appendChild(imageFruit);
          newFruit.addEventListener("animationend", function() {container.removeChild(newFruit);}, false);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var timeStart;
var timer;

function createFruit() {
  // any logic
}

function Go() {
  if((new Date()).getTime() - timeStart.getTime() > 1000*30) {
     window.clearInterval(timer);
     console.log("stop");
     return;
  }
  
  console.log("go");
  createFruit();
}

function StartTimer() {
   timeStart = new Date();
   timer = window.setInterval(Go,1000);
}
 
StartTimer();
```

Comment: Дмитрий, а если мы используем паузу ?

Comment: @RomanVerner не понял?

Comment: @RomanVerner данная функция работает ровно 30 секунд и срабатывает каждую секунду

Comment: Ну получается если мы нажимаем на кнопку, и включается пауза. Например так:



`button.onclick = function() {
  for(let i = 0; i < fruitInHtml.length; i++) {
    fruitInHtml[i].classList.toggle('paused');
  }
}`

Comment: @RomanVerner так после каждого вызова createFruit будет пауза в 1 секунду, конечно размер паузы можно настроить

Comment: @RomanVerner Или вы хотите в конце CreateFruit сделать паузу а потом выполнить что-то?

Comment: У нас есть таймер, который идет в течение 30 секунд после нажатия на кнопку, и выполняется функция, после того как она выполнилась и закончилась анимация у элементов, нужно выполнить функцию снова. Есть пользователь нажал на кнопку стоп, анимация заканчивается. Собственно в этом и возник вопрос, нужно выполнять функцию после того как закончилась аниммация

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, мне нужно рекурсия. Вызывать функцию сначала после окончания анимации

Comment: @RomanVerner рекурсией, или просто её в цикл оберните `while(true) {}`, предпочтительнее цикл, так как рекурсия может завеситься при переполнении стека